# Pytorch not utilizing GPU despite all settings seemingly correct

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I've got a CUDA 10.2 on a 2070 SUPER card and

```
import torch

torch.cuda.is_available()
```

returns `true`.

```
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
```

returns `2070 SUPER` correctly.

The code I'm running specifies using CUDA:

```
import shutil
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import argparse
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchsample.transforms import RandomRotate, RandomTranslate, RandomFlip, ToTensor, Compose, RandomAffine
from torchvision import transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

from dataloader import MRDataset
import model

from sklearn import metrics


def train_model(model, train_loader, epoch, num_epochs, optimizer, writer, current_lr, log_every=100):
    _ = model.train()

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model.cuda()

    y_preds = []
    y_trues = []
    losses = []

    for i, (image, label, weight) in enumerate(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            image = image.cuda()
            label = label.cuda()
            weight = weight.cuda()

        label = label[0]
        weight = weight[0]

        prediction = model.forward(image.float())

        loss = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(weight=weight)(prediction, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        loss_value = loss.item()
        losses.append(loss_value)

        probas = torch.sigmoid(prediction)

        y_trues.append(int(label[0][1]))
        y_preds.append(probas[0][1].item())

        try:
            auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_trues, y_preds)
        except:
            auc = 0.5

        writer.add_scalar('Train/Loss', loss_value,
                          epoch * len(train_loader) + i)
        writer.add_scalar('Train/AUC', auc, epoch * len(train_loader) + i)

        if (i % log_every == 0) & (i > 0):
            print('''[Epoch: {0} / {1} |Single batch number : {2} / {3} ]| avg train loss {4} | train auc : {5} | lr : {6}'''.
                  format(
                      epoch + 1,
                      num_epochs,
                      i,
                      len(train_loader),
                      np.round(np.mean(losses), 4),
                      np.round(auc, 4),
                      current_lr
                  )
                  )

    writer.add_scalar('Train/AUC_epoch', auc, epoch + i)

    train_loss_epoch = np.round(np.mean(losses), 4)
    train_auc_epoch = np.round(auc, 4)
    return train_loss_epoch, train_auc_epoch


def evaluate_model(model, val_loader, epoch, num_epochs, writer, current_lr, log_every=20):
    _ = model.eval()

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model.cuda()

    y_trues = []
    y_preds = []
    losses = []

    for i, (image, label, weight) in enumerate(val_loader):

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            image = image.cuda()
            label = label.cuda()
            weight = weight.cuda()

        label = label[0]
        weight = weight[0]

        prediction = model.forward(image.float())

        loss = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(weight=weight)(prediction, label)

        loss_value = loss.item()
        losses.append(loss_value)

        probas = torch.sigmoid(prediction)

        y_trues.append(int(label[0][1]))
        y_preds.append(probas[0][1].item())

        try:
            auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_trues, y_preds)
        except:
            auc = 0.5

        writer.add_scalar('Val/Loss', loss_value, epoch * len(val_loader) + i)
        writer.add_scalar('Val/AUC', auc, epoch * len(val_loader) + i)

        if (i % log_every == 0) & (i > 0):
            print('''[Epoch: {0} / {1} |Single batch number : {2} / {3} ] | avg val loss {4} | val auc : {5} | lr : {6}'''.
                  format(
                      epoch + 1,
                      num_epochs,
                      i,
                      len(val_loader),
                      np.round(np.mean(losses), 4),
                      np.round(auc, 4),
                      current_lr
                  )
                  )

    writer.add_scalar('Val/AUC_epoch', auc, epoch + i)

    val_loss_epoch = np.round(np.mean(losses), 4)
    val_auc_epoch = np.round(auc, 4)
    return val_loss_epoch, val_auc_epoch

def get_lr(optimizer):
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        return param_group['lr']


def run(args):
    log_root_folder = "./logs/{0}/{1}/".format(args.task, args.plane)
    if args.flush_history == 1:
        objects = os.listdir(log_root_folder)
        for f in objects:
            if os.path.isdir(log_root_folder + f):
                shutil.rmtree(log_root_folder + f)

    now = datetime.now()
    logdir = log_root_folder + now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "/"
    os.makedirs(logdir)

    writer = SummaryWriter(logdir)

    augmentor = Compose([
        transforms.Lambda(lambda x: torch.Tensor(x)),
        RandomRotate(25),
        RandomTranslate([0.11, 0.11]),
        RandomFlip(),
        transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x.repeat(3, 1, 1, 1).permute(1, 0, 2, 3)),
    ])

    train_dataset = MRDataset('./data/', args.task,
                              args.plane, transform=augmentor, train=True)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=0, drop_last=False)

    validation_dataset = MRDataset(
        './data/', args.task, args.plane, train=False)
    validation_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        validation_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=-True, num_workers=0, drop_last=False)

    mrnet = model.MRNet()

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        mrnet = mrnet.cuda()

    optimizer = optim.Adam(mrnet.parameters(), lr=args.lr, weight_decay=0.1)

    if args.lr_scheduler == "plateau":
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(
            optimizer, patience=3, factor=.3, threshold=1e-4, verbose=True)
    elif args.lr_scheduler == "step":
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(
            optimizer, step_size=3, gamma=args.gamma)

    best_val_loss = float('inf')
    best_val_auc = float(0)

    num_epochs = args.epochs
    iteration_change_loss = 0
    patience = args.patience
    log_every = args.log_every

    t_start_training = time.time()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        current_lr = get_lr(optimizer)

        t_start = time.time()
        
        train_loss, train_auc = train_model(
            mrnet, train_loader, epoch, num_epochs, optimizer, writer, current_lr, log_every)
        val_loss, val_auc = evaluate_model(
            mrnet, validation_loader, epoch, num_epochs, writer, current_lr)

        if args.lr_scheduler == 'plateau':
            scheduler.step(val_loss)
        elif args.lr_scheduler == 'step':
            scheduler.step()

        t_end = time.time()
        delta = t_end - t_start

        print("train loss : {0} | train auc {1} | val loss {2} | val auc {3} | elapsed time {4} s".format(
            train_loss, train_auc, val_loss, val_auc, delta))

        iteration_change_loss += 1
        print('-' * 30)

        if val_auc > best_val_auc:
            best_val_auc = val_auc
            if bool(args.save_model):
                file_name = f'model_{args.prefix_name}_{args.task}_{args.plane}_val_auc_{val_auc:0.4f}_train_auc_{train_auc:0.4f}_epoch_{epoch+1}.pth'
                for f in os.listdir('./models/'):
                    if (args.task in f) and (args.plane in f) and (args.prefix_name in f):
                        os.remove(f'./models/{f}')
                torch.save(mrnet, f'./models/{file_name}')

        if val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = val_loss
            iteration_change_loss = 0

        if iteration_change_loss == patience:
            print('Early stopping after {0} iterations without the decrease of the val loss'.
                  format(iteration_change_loss))
            break

    t_end_training = time.time()
    print(f'training took {t_end_training - t_start_training} s')


def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--task', type=str, required=True,
                        choices=['abnormal', 'acl', 'meniscus'])
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--plane', type=str, required=True,
                        choices=['sagittal', 'coronal', 'axial'])
    parser.add_argument('--prefix_name', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--augment', type=int, choices=[0, 1], default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--lr_scheduler', type=str,
                        default='plateau', choices=['plateau', 'step'])
    parser.add_argument('--gamma', type=float, default=0.5)
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=50)
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=1e-5)
    parser.add_argument('--flush_history', type=int, choices=[0, 1], default=0)
    parser.add_argument('--save_model', type=int, choices=[0, 1], default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--patience', type=int, default=5)
    parser.add_argument('--log_every', type=int, default=100)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_arguments()
    run(args)
```

However, running `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=index,gpu_name,memory.total,memory.used,memory.free,temperature.gpu,pstate,utilization.gpu,utilization.memory --format=csv`

returns `0, GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER, 8192 MiB, 2774 MiB, 5418 MiB, 53, P2, 9 %, 5 %` while the model is training. This is not utilizing the GPU at all.

Anyone has any idea what is wrong here?

EDIT: As per the comment I've received I have tried to more explicitly tell the model to only use CUDA. However to no avail. Here's the new code:

```
import shutil
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import argparse
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchsample.transforms import RandomRotate, RandomTranslate, RandomFlip, ToTensor, Compose, RandomAffine
from torchvision import transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

from dataloader import MRDataset
import model

from sklearn import metrics


torch.cuda.is_available()

def train_model(model, train_loader, epoch, num_epochs, optimizer, writer, current_lr, log_every=100):
    _ = model.train()

    device = torch.device('cuda:0')

    y_preds = []
    y_trues = []
    losses = []

    for i, (image, label, weight) in enumerate(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        image = image.to(device)
        label = label.to(device)
        weight = weight.to(device)

        label = label[0]
        weight = weight[0]

        prediction = model.forward(image.float())

        loss = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(weight=weight)(prediction, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        loss_value = loss.item()
        losses.append(loss_value)

        probas = torch.sigmoid(prediction)

        y_trues.append(int(label[0][1]))
        y_preds.append(probas[0][1].item())

        try:
            auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_trues, y_preds)
        except:
            auc = 0.5

        writer.add_scalar('Train/Loss', loss_value,
                          epoch * len(train_loader) + i)
        writer.add_scalar('Train/AUC', auc, epoch * len(train_loader) + i)

        if (i % log_every == 0) & (i > 0):
            print('''[Epoch: {0} / {1} |Single batch number : {2} / {3} ]| avg train loss {4} | train auc : {5} | lr : {6}'''.
                  format(
                      epoch + 1,
                      num_epochs,
                      i,
                      len(train_loader),
                      np.round(np.mean(losses), 4),
                      np.round(auc, 4),
                      current_lr
                  )
                  )

    writer.add_scalar('Train/AUC_epoch', auc, epoch + i)

    train_loss_epoch = np.round(np.mean(losses), 4)
    train_auc_epoch = np.round(auc, 4)
    return train_loss_epoch, train_auc_epoch


def evaluate_model(model, val_loader, epoch, num_epochs, writer, current_lr, log_every=20):
    _ = model.eval()


    model.cuda()

    y_trues = []
    y_preds = []
    losses = []

    for i, (image, label, weight) in enumerate(val_loader):


        image = image.to(device)
        label = label.to(device)
        weight = weight.to(device)

        label = label[0]
        weight = weight[0]

        prediction = model.forward(image.float())

        loss = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(weight=weight)(prediction, label)

        loss_value = loss.item()
        losses.append(loss_value)

        probas = torch.sigmoid(prediction)

        y_trues.append(int(label[0][1]))
        y_preds.append(probas[0][1].item())

        try:
            auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_trues, y_preds)
        except:
            auc = 0.5

        writer.add_scalar('Val/Loss', loss_value, epoch * len(val_loader) + i)
        writer.add_scalar('Val/AUC', auc, epoch * len(val_loader) + i)

        if (i % log_every == 0) & (i > 0):
            print('''[Epoch: {0} / {1} |Single batch number : {2} / {3} ] | avg val loss {4} | val auc : {5} | lr : {6}'''.
                  format(
                      epoch + 1,
                      num_epochs,
                      i,
                      len(val_loader),
                      np.round(np.mean(losses), 4),
                      np.round(auc, 4),
                      current_lr
                  )
                  )

    writer.add_scalar('Val/AUC_epoch', auc, epoch + i)

    val_loss_epoch = np.round(np.mean(losses), 4)
    val_auc_epoch = np.round(auc, 4)
    return val_loss_epoch, val_auc_epoch

def get_lr(optimizer):
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        return param_group['lr']


def run(args):
    log_root_folder = "./logs/{0}/{1}/".format(args.task, args.plane)
    if args.flush_history == 1:
        objects = os.listdir(log_root_folder)
        for f in objects:
            if os.path.isdir(log_root_folder + f):
                shutil.rmtree(log_root_folder + f)

    now = datetime.now()
    logdir = log_root_folder + now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "/"
    os.makedirs(logdir)

    writer = SummaryWriter(logdir)

    augmentor = Compose([
        transforms.Lambda(lambda x: torch.Tensor(x)),
        RandomRotate(25),
        RandomTranslate([0.11, 0.11]),
        RandomFlip(),
        transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x.repeat(3, 1, 1, 1).permute(1, 0, 2, 3)),
    ])

    train_dataset = MRDataset('./data/', args.task,
                              args.plane, transform=augmentor, train=True)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=0, drop_last=False)

    validation_dataset = MRDataset(
        './data/', args.task, args.plane, train=False)
    validation_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        validation_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=-True, num_workers=0, drop_last=False)

    mrnet = model.MRNet()

    mrnet = mrnet.cuda()

    optimizer = optim.Adam(mrnet.parameters(), lr=args.lr, weight_decay=0.1)

    if args.lr_scheduler == "plateau":
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(
            optimizer, patience=3, factor=.3, threshold=1e-4, verbose=True)
    elif args.lr_scheduler == "step":
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(
            optimizer, step_size=3, gamma=args.gamma)

    best_val_loss = float('inf')
    best_val_auc = float(0)

    num_epochs = args.epochs
    iteration_change_loss = 0
    patience = args.patience
    log_every = args.log_every

    t_start_training = time.time()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        current_lr = get_lr(optimizer)

        t_start = time.time()
        
        train_loss, train_auc = train_model(
            mrnet, train_loader, epoch, num_epochs, optimizer, writer, current_lr, log_every)
        val_loss, val_auc = evaluate_model(
            mrnet, validation_loader, epoch, num_epochs, writer, current_lr)

        if args.lr_scheduler == 'plateau':
            scheduler.step(val_loss)
        elif args.lr_scheduler == 'step':
            scheduler.step()

        t_end = time.time()
        delta = t_end - t_start

        print("train loss : {0} | train auc {1} | val loss {2} | val auc {3} | elapsed time {4} s".format(
            train_loss, train_auc, val_loss, val_auc, delta))

        iteration_change_loss += 1
        print('-' * 30)

        if val_auc > best_val_auc:
            best_val_auc = val_auc
            if bool(args.save_model):
                file_name = f'model_{args.prefix_name}_{args.task}_{args.plane}_val_auc_{val_auc:0.4f}_train_auc_{train_auc:0.4f}_epoch_{epoch+1}.pth'
                for f in os.listdir('./models/'):
                    if (args.task in f) and (args.plane in f) and (args.prefix_name in f):
                        os.remove(f'./models/{f}')
                torch.save(mrnet, f'./models/{file_name}')

        if val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = val_loss
            iteration_change_loss = 0

        if iteration_change_loss == patience:
            print('Early stopping after {0} iterations without the decrease of the val loss'.
                  format(iteration_change_loss))
            break

    t_end_training = time.time()
    print(f'training took {t_end_training - t_start_training} s')


def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--task', type=str, required=True,
                        choices=['abnormal', 'acl', 'meniscus'])
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--plane', type=str, required=True,
                        choices=['sagittal', 'coronal', 'axial'])
    parser.add_argument('--prefix_name', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--augment', type=int, choices=[0, 1], default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--lr_scheduler', type=str,
                        default='plateau', choices=['plateau', 'step'])
    parser.add_argument('--gamma', type=float, default=0.5)
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=50)
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=1e-5)
    parser.add_argument('--flush_history', type=int, choices=[0, 1], default=0)
    parser.add_argument('--save_model', type=int, choices=[0, 1], default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--patience', type=int, default=5)
    parser.add_argument('--log_every', type=int, default=100)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_arguments()
    run(args)
```

Comment: May be you should move your model to GPU before setting it to train mode. I also recommend you to use device variable instead of if statement `if torch.cuda.is_available()` like this: `device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')`, `model.to(device)`, `image.to(device)`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to "move model to GPU"? I've worked in tensorflow before where just stating that if the GPU was available then the model should be trained using the GPU. Can you elaborate on this statement?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and implemented an edit. It did unfortunately not help.,

Comment: call `model.cuda()` before `model.train()`

Comment: As such? https://pastebin.com/9hQkke9x

Unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: It's as if it is indeed using GPU but something is prohibiting it from utilizing it. I'm not sure where such a bottleneck would be.